# gap locks don't appear in data_locks table - What's happening?

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustered-index, unique-index, non-clustered-index

Window 1:

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table1 where id > 99 FOR UPDATE;
+-----+--------+--------+-------+------+
| id  | field1 | field2 | field | a    |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+------+
| 101 | hola   | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
| 103 | yo     | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
| 107 | hey    | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Window 2:

```
mysql> SELECT thread_id, event_id,
    -> object_schema, object_name, index_name,
    -> lock_type, lock_mode, lock_status, lock_data
    -> FROM performance_schema.data_locks
    -> WHERE thread_id = 279\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    thread_id: 279
     event_id: 28
object_schema: laravel_doc
  object_name: table1
   index_name: NULL
    lock_type: TABLE
    lock_mode: IX
  lock_status: GRANTED
    lock_data: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
    thread_id: 279
     event_id: 28
object_schema: laravel_doc
  object_name: table1
   index_name: PRIMARY
    lock_type: RECORD
    lock_mode: X
  lock_status: GRANTED
    lock_data: supremum pseudo-record
*************************** 3. row ***************************
    thread_id: 279
     event_id: 28
object_schema: laravel_doc
  object_name: table1
   index_name: PRIMARY
    lock_type: RECORD
    lock_mode: X
  lock_status: GRANTED
    lock_data: 101
*************************** 4. row ***************************
    thread_id: 279
     event_id: 28
object_schema: laravel_doc
  object_name: table1
   index_name: PRIMARY
    lock_type: RECORD
    lock_mode: X
  lock_status: GRANTED
    lock_data: 103
*************************** 5. row ***************************
    thread_id: 279
     event_id: 28
object_schema: laravel_doc
  object_name: table1
   index_name: PRIMARY
    lock_type: RECORD
    lock_mode: X
  lock_status: GRANTED
    lock_data: 107
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Original table:

```
+-----+--------+--------+-------+------+
| id  | field1 | field2 | field | a    |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+------+
|   3 | hello  | 1      | NULL  | NULL |
|  97 | hi     | 2      | NULL  | NULL |
| 101 | hola   | 3      | NULL  | NULL |
| 103 | yo     | 4      | NULL  | NULL |
| 107 | hey    | 5      | NULL  | NULL |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+------+
```

**Gap locks don't appear**, they should be displayed because **I checked and it prevents me from INSERT for example with id = 102 (in window 2)**

"id" is the primary key

> For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE), UPDATE, and
> DELETE statements, the locks that are taken depend on whether the
> statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition or a
> range-type search condition.
>
> For a unique index with a unique search condition, InnoDB locks only      the index record found, not the gap before it.
>
> For other search conditions, and for non-unique indexes, InnoDB locks the index range scanned, using gap locks or next-key locks to
> block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range.
> For information about gap locks and next-key locks, see
> Section 15.7.1, “InnoDB Locking”.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

**Also, they should appear because is an unique index BUT A RANGE SEARCH, not a unique search condition**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact they are, they are just not visible to the naked eye:

**Record X = Record lock + gap lock = Next-key lock**

https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/innodb-data-locking-part-2-locks/

> S → is like a combination of S,REC_NOT_GAP and S,GAP at the same time.
> So it is a shared access right to the row, and prevents insert before
> it.
>
> X → is like a combination of X,REC_NOT_GAP and X,GAP at the same time.
> So it is an exclusive access right to the row, and prevents insert
> before it.

https://xhinliang.win/2021/09/backend/innodb-locks/

> LOCK_MODE has several options
>
> ```
> IX -> Intention Exclusive Lock
> IS -> Intention Share Lock
> X,REC_NOT_GAP -> Exclusive Record Lock
> X,GAP -> Exclusive Gap Lock
> X -> Exclusive Next-Key Lock
> S,REC_NOT_GAP -> Share Record Lock
> S,GAP -> Share Gap Lock
> S -> Share Next-Key Lock
> ```